# Pass information from selection in form when calling from db

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project and I can not seem to get this right no mater what I do.

I have 3 tables in db, year, manufacturer_id and models

I would like to display makes and models based on requests made by user. I.e., if a user selects Make as Ford and then Year as 1942 the Model should return a list of all models produced in that year. However it does not work can some one tell me where I am going wrong please.

My data bases tables are set up as follows.

manufacturer
2 columns id (which is unique) and manufacturer

year
2 columns id (which is unique) and year

model
4 columns id (which is unique) year (which corresponds to year id table) manufacturer_id (which corresponds to manufactures id table) and model.

The code I am using is as follows.

```
 <tr>
<td align="right" label for='formyear'>Year: </td>
<td><select name="formyear">
<?php 
$sql="SELECT id,year FROM year";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['year'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" label for='formmake'>Make: </td>
<td><select name="formmake" id="formmake" onchange="return populateModel(this.value);">
<?php 
$sql="SELECT id,manufacturer FROM manufacturer";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['manufacturer'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" label for='formmodel'>Model: </td>
<td><select name="formmodel" id="formmodel">
<?php 
$sql="SELECT id,manufacturer_id,model FROM model WHERE year='1'";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['model'] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>

                                </select>
```

I seem to be makeing a mess of this. I would like to thank everyone who looks at this for there help.

Comment: when a year is selected, do you want the manufacturer filter to remain or you want just the list of all models in that year irrespective of manufacturer?

Comment: No I would like only the models for the manufacturer selected returned for the year selected. I need to keep teh year, make and model to place into the db when the form is posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you are serious use PDO.

Having said that I would put the year in the model table. yes you would have multiple entries for a given model, but to have a separate table for year means you 
   would have to associate that year with all relevant models, 
   obviously years for each model differ. just add a year field, 
    `INNER JOIN` on the make ID

I am not a car person but probably less models than years, 
       in which case adding model Id to years table would be 
       less entries.

if you were using the years table for something else,
    i.e. a form for users to submit their info... use a year ID
    in the model table and INNER JOIN all three.

the point remains the same though... you have multiple
       model table rows, one for each year

Comment: Hi thank you for your coment. I have not used inner joins befor and was wondering how to do it? In my model table I have year colum that relates to the year table id. I have multiple entries for each model due to this which is based off the year table using the id colum. How would I use the inner join? Sorry i am new to php

Answer (score 0):

For both the year as well as the manufacturer dropdown, on change, fetch the values of both the year and manufacturer selected in the javascript function (assume empty if not set).

Then, for fetching the relevant columns, you can send an ajax call to a php file with the above values as parameters. In that php file, you can just check for the models based on data sent:

```
$year=(isset($_REQUEST['year']) && $_REQUEST['year']!='')?$_REQUEST['year']:'';
$mfr_id=(isset($_REQUEST['mfr_id']) && $_REQUEST['mfr_id']!='')?$_REQUEST['mfr_id']:'';

$sql="SELECT id,model FROM model";
if($year!='')
{
    $sql.=" WHERE year=".$year;
    if($mfr_id!='')
        $sql.=" and manufacturer_id=".$mfr_id;
}
else
{
    if($mfr_id!='')
        $sql.=" WHERE manufacturer_id=".$mfr_id;
}
$result =mysql_query($sql);
```

The rows in the resultset will be filtered based on your criteria.

Comment: Ok sorry but you have lost me. Could you explain what javascript I would need and as I dont use Ajax what sort of code I would need. Also where does all this fit in?

Comment: what exactly do you do for `populateModel()`? I guessed you must be using ajax? You want to load the contents of model on changing year and manufacturer, right? That's why, loading by ajax.